# rabbitmq-plugins failed to run as rabbitmq user

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm using RabbitMQ 3.7.5.

I created a docker image which run rabbitmq as rabbitmq user.
But I failed to run rabbitmq-plugins.
bash-4.2$ rabbitmq-plugins list

```
Usage:
rabbitmq-plugins [-n <node>] [-l] [-q] <command> [<command options>]

 .......
<timeout> - operation timeout in seconds. Default is "infinity".

Only root or rabbitmq can run rabbitmq-plugins
```

bash-4.2$ id

```
uid=10000(rabbitmq) gid=10000(rabbitmq) groups=10000(rabbitmq),1(bin)
```

bash-4.2$ rabbitmqctl cluster_status

```
Cluster status of node rabbit@zt-crmq-0 ...
[{nodes,[{disc,['rabbit@zt-crmq-0','rabbit@zt-crmq-1','rabbit@zt-crmq-2']}]},
 {running_nodes,['rabbit@zt-crmq-2','rabbit@zt-crmq-1','rabbit@zt-crmq-0']},
 {cluster_name,<<"rabbit@zt-crmq-0.zt-crmq.default.svc.cluster.local">>},
 {partitions,[]},
 {alarms,[{'rabbit@zt-crmq-2',[]},
          {'rabbit@zt-crmq-1',[]},
          {'rabbit@zt-crmq-0',[]}]}]
```

for /usr/sbin/rabbitm-plugins:

```
 main() {
  ensure_we_are_in_a_readable_dir
  if current_user_is_rabbitmq && calling_rabbitmq_server
  then
    exec_rabbitmq_server "$@"
  elif current_user_is_rabbitmq && ! calling_rabbitmq_plugins
  then
    exec_script_as_rabbitmq "$@"
  elif current_user_is_root && calling_rabbitmq_plugins
  then
    exec_script_as_rabbitmq "$@"
  elif current_user_is_root
  then
    exec_script_as_root "$@"
  else
    run_script_help_and_fail
  fi
}
```

why it judges not to run rabbitmq_plugins as rabbitmq user?

Any help will be appreiated.

B.R,
Tao

Answer (score 2):

The if-statements in the `main()` indeed don't let us run `rabbitmq-plugins` from `rabbitmq` user. Not sure if this is expected or just a bug but you can
circumvent the script altogether with:

```
$ /usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-plugins list | grep hash
[E*] rabbitmq_consistent_hash_exchange 3.8.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the rabbitmq user to the docker group. If the docker group does not exist create the group and then add rabbitmq to the docker group.